# On $\int_1^\infty \left| \frac{\sin x}{x} \right|\cdot \left| \frac{\sin x}{x} \right|^{1/2}\cdots\left| \frac{\sin x}{x} \right|^{1/N}dx$

Tags: real-analysis, convergence-divergence, improper-integrals

We know the example $$\int_1^\infty  \left|  \frac{\sin x}{x}  \right| dx=\infty.$$

I wondered what about $$\int_1^\infty  \left|  \frac{\sin x}{x}  \right|\cdot \left|  \frac{\sin x}{x}  \right|^{1/2}\cdots\left|  \frac{\sin x}{x}  \right|^{1/N}dx,\tag{1}$$ and $$\int_1^\infty  \prod_{k=1}^\infty\left|  \frac{\sin x}{x}  \right|^{1/k}dx.\tag{2} $$

> **Question.** Do converge $(1)$ for some integer $N>1$? And what about the convergence of $(2)$? **Many thanks.**

Comment: The integral is simplified to $\int_1^{\infty} \left|  \frac{\sin x}{x}  \right| ^ {H_N}\,dx$ where $H_N = \sum_{i=1}^N \frac{1}{i}$ tends to infinity as $N\to \infty$.

Comment: Many thanks, now I can not conclude nothing. Of course I know that $\left|  \frac{\sin x}{x}  \right|\leq 1$ and thus from your hint the integrand tends to 0. Tomorrow I see it. Any case many thanks for your help @Opt

Comment: @user243301 $\sin x$ is bounded by 1 from above, so you can bound your integral from above by $x^{-H_N}$. This shows that already for $N=2$ the integral converges. (And the infinite product in your (2) diverges to zero, so you're integrating zero there.)

Comment: Many thanks @StevenStadnicki now I see, after the solution that you propose and the details of the answer below, that my exampe was easy using the comparison test for integrals, and the convergence $\int_1^\infty\frac{1}{x^a}dx=\frac{1}{a-1}$ for $\Re a>1$.I believe that the limit case follows from dominated convergence.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The solution taken from the comments is rather simple. For $n\ge2$,

$$\prod_{k=1}^n\left|\frac{\sin x}x\right|^{1/k}\le\frac1{x^{H_n}}$$

where $H_n=1+\frac12+\dots+\frac1n$ are the harmonic numbers. Since $H_n>1$, we have that

$$I(n)=\int_1^\infty\prod_{k=1}^n\left|\frac{\sin x}x\right|^{1/k}~\mathrm dx\le\int_1^\infty\frac1{x^{H_n}}~\mathrm dx=\frac1{H_n-1}<\infty$$

As $n\to\infty$, we also have

$$I(n)\to0$$

since $H_n\to\infty$.

Comment: Many thanks now I see (after the solution of Steven and your answer) that my exampe was easy using the comparison test for integrals, and the convergence $\int_1^\infty\frac{1}{x^a}dx=\frac{1}{a-1}$ for $\Re a>1$.